# Is it correct to say "I have the economic and financial legal capacity"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am translating a sworn statement into English. Is it correct to say "I have the economic and financial legal capacity"? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. It is impossible for us to know whether the translation would be accurate without a description of the concept you are trying to translate. Such a sentence would be unusual (as the relationship between *financial* and *legal* is unclear), but legal language has many constructions that would never be used in day-to-day communication. Please [edit](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/55262/edit) your post to provide some additional context.

Comment: I think economic is mixed into the muddle too.  Could be a list of three things (in which case 'and' is misplaced and 1 or 2 commas are needed), could be that 'legal' applies to both 'economic' and 'financial', or could be that 'financial legal' is intended as a unit.  So as suggested above, you need to elaborate what you are trying to communicate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is requesting help with a translation, and is not about learning English.

Answer (score 1):

In English, one can act *in a legal capacity*, for example, as the *fiduciary* of a *trust.* If one *has* the *legal capacity* to do something, one has the legal right to do so.

One can have the *economic capacity* or *financial capacity* to do something, such as purchase a company, or start a business. Financial capacity and economic capacity are more or less synonymous.  Simply put, one has the capital at one's disposal to accomplish the goal.

Comment: It's true that financial and economic are close especially for individuals. But I'd say financial refers more strictly to monetary and liquid assets.  Your finances cover your assets and cash flow.  Your economy can involve labor, raw materials, goods, etc.  Of course economics translate into finances--but not without mechanisms and markets.  On the individual level, in 'home economics' terms, the distinction is weaker but still present--eg frugality in consumption can benefit household finances.

Comment: Dear friends, in my case, 'legal' applies to both 'economic' and 'financial'. Though, following your comments, I am going to omit 'legal' and write 'I have the economic and financial capacity'. Unfortunately, I do not have more context. What I am translating is a table with data on participation in a tender. There are short sentences such as 'I declare that I have the legal capacity.' in the table, without any further explanation. Thank you for the kind help! Have a great day/evening/night/morning!